# Memory allocator causing mysterious pause

Tags: c++, memory-management

I should probably be sleeping. Instead, I'm coding. Specifically, I've written The World's Worse Memory Allocator(TM). It's got an array of bytes (chars) to use for memory for stuff; it's got a list of used memory blocks; it's got an index to allocate memory from. It even allocates memory. Deallocates, not so much.
That shouldn't be a problem, though, as to the best of my knowledge, nothing is new'd outside of the array and list classes and the destructor for those is called the proper number of times.

Edit: The problem is, the program enters what appears to be an infinite loop somewhere in the c++ back-end code itself, shortly after the MemoryManager's destructor is called. In fact, if the MemoryManager is put inside the Try-Catch block, the program never makes it outside the Try-Catch block. I need to know why and how to fix it, please, thanks.

This is the main loop which is doing terribly important allocations:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])  
{  
    MemoryManager memoryManager = MemoryManager(1024);  

    try  
    {  

        int * n;  
        for (int t = 0; t < 32; ++t)  
        {  
            n = (int*)memoryManager.Allocate(4);  
        }  
    } catch (char* str) { std::cout << str; }  

    return 0;  
}
```

And the MemoryManager, in all it's newbie glory:

```
// A memory manager

#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Array.h"
#include "SmartPointer.h"


class MemBlock
{
public:
    unsigned int Start;
    unsigned int End;

    MemBlock() { Start = 0; End = 0; }

    MemBlock(unsigned int start, unsigned int end)
    {
        Start = start; End = end;
    }
    ~MemBlock() { }
};


class MemoryManager
{
private:
    Array<char> memory;
    List<MemBlock> memBlocks;
    int index;

public:
    MemoryManager(unsigned int size)
    {
        memory = Array<char>(size);
        memBlocks = List<MemBlock>(size / 24);
        index = 0;
    }
    ~MemoryManager() { }


    void* Allocate(unsigned int size)
    {
        memBlocks.Add(&MemBlock(index, index + size));
        void* r = (void*)(memory.insecureAccess + index);
        index += size;
        return r;
    }
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Uh, you seem to have forgotten to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have asked a question here, but I'm going to point out a horrible flaw in your approach anyway :)

If you are planning to write a `Deallocate(void*)` method then you are going to struggle.
You can match the `void*` pointer against your `memBlocks` list to determine which `MemBlock` it is, but you will only be able to reduce `index` if that `MemBlock` happens to be the last one returned by `Allocate` otherwise it is just a free hole in your array.

For a basic solution to this you would need a list of the free blocks and you would take allocated blocks from that list, and add them back to the list when they were deallocated.

This approach is called a free list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list

Comment: ...Whoops. I'll add the question in. And thanks - The pattern I was planning on using is deallocating in the opposite order of allocation (for which, my unposted, unfinished MemoryPointer class would probably be useful, but I hadn't got that far). Anyway, I've now got that link open in another tab.

Comment: Well, implied question in posting the problem.

Comment: @Narf the Mouse: Cool, well if you plan to always deallocate in the opposite order to allocation then you are basically creating a Stack, so you might want to look at that type/pattern for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Error in ignorance; it was an indirect error. I was using "delete theArray;" in the Array destructor (Array also being the base class of List) when I should have been using "delete [] theArray". The pause is now gone and the problem seems solved. Thanks for your time.